# Run bash script with pip install

Tags: python, build, pip, setuptools

I have created a wrapper for `c++` library using `python`.

I have a `bash` script that will download `c++` code, compile it and copy the generated `.so` file to the python package. 
Then I have written the `setup.py` so that when you use `pip install package-name`, it will install the `.so` file also.

What I need is to run that `bash` script when I type `pip install package-name`. Currently what I have to do is run the `bash` script first and then use `pip install package-name` to install.

And I need to upload the code to the [*Python Package Index*](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/#generating-distribution-archives). So the solution has to be compatible with that also*.

PS: I know about the `Extension` module in `setuptools`. I can't use that because I need to download something and run a `Makefile` after editing it. I do all of that with the `bash` script.

***** I learnt that this requirement is not possible. So please ignore that one.

Thank you..

Comment: If you want to upload it to PyPI you should stick to the usual way of installation. That means that C(++) libraries are expected to be present already. They could be installed via many different ways and you are enforcing one with your script. This is especially important when it is a commonly used library or a system that does not support your build process.

Comment: If you need to download something and run your scripts, do it in the wheel build phase.